# Payment plan is accepted and created, but $0 is sent instead of the amount due

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using **Ruby on Rails 4**, and the **PayPal REST SDK**.

I've created a plan (recurring) and an agreement, and the user agreed to the plan, and this user has a subscription for the plan.

#### The plan and agreement:

```
plan = PayPal::SDK::REST::Plan.new(
  name: 'test month', description: 'test desc', type: 'INFINITE',
  payment_definitions:
    [
      {
        name: 'Payment',
        type: "REGULAR",
        frequency: 'MONTH',
        frequency_interval: 1, cycles: 0,
        amount:
          {currency: 'USD', value: '10'}
      }
    ],
  merchant_preferences:
    {
      cancel_url: 'https://google.com/',
      return_url: 'https://google.com/',
      auto_bill_amount: 'YES'
    }
  )

plan.create
plan.update(path: '/', op: 'replace', value: { state: 'ACTIVE' })

agreement = PayPal::SDK::REST::Agreement.new(
  name: 'test agreement',
  description: 'agreement desc',
  plan: {id: plan.id},
  start_date: (DateTime.current + 1.minute).to_s,
  payer: {
    payment_method: 'paypal'
  }
)

agreement.create

agreement.execute
```

## The user's subscription:

[image]

But the payment (transaction) was not created.

As you can see **Amount sent** is `$0`, but the **Amount due each cycle** is `$10.00`.

Why was `$0` sent, why was the amount due, `$10`, not sent?

Thanks.